# The ide keeps saying the Traceback (most recent call last): grid[i].append(thing) IndexError: list index out of range, why is this happeneing?

Tags: python, arrays

grid = []
math = 1

for i in range(10):

```
thing = input("number " + str(i+1) +" = ")
grid[i].append(thing)
if i == 10:
    for j in len(10):
        math + grid[j]
```

print("sum = ", math , "square root =", math/10)

Comment: You're using `for j in len(10):`. This shouldn't be working. You should be getting a different error. Please add more context about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

should just be `grid.append(thing)`

what you are doing is the item at index i, append to that.
But since the list is empty, and has no objects, you are trying to append to an object at index 0, when there is none.